# Gradle Build failed Could not initialize CrashlyticsPlugin

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics, google-fabric

When I try to build projects gradle I get this error:

```
Could not initialize class com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin
```

Project Gradle is:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
    maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
}
dependencies {
    ...
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'
    ...
  }
}
```

And app gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric' // got error here
```

Answer (score 0):

Fabric/Firebaser here - if you're integrating Firebase Crashlytics, make sure you've followed all the steps in this doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android. If you didn't include the rest of the app-level build.gradle changes it would cause some errors.

If you're integrating with the Fabric Crashlytics instructions (https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install) similarly make sure you have the Crashlytics SDK in your app-level build.gradle, and that you're correctly importing and initializing Crashlytics in your start Activity.

Also make sure that you're on the latest Crashlytics dependencies. You may also have to update Gradle/the Android Gradle plugin, as this error has come up before when running out of date Gradle versions.

Answer (score 0):

Just do "Invalidate Caches / Restart"